# If $A$ and $B$ are two matrices, calculate $L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}S_k,$ where $S_k$ is the sum of elements of $A^{2k+1}+B^{2k+1}$

Tags: matrices, algebra-precalculus, limits, solution-verification

> If $A$ and $B$ are two matrices,
> $$A=\begin{bmatrix}-1 & -\frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} & 1\end{bmatrix} \\ B=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 3 \\ -\frac{1}{9} & -\frac{1}{3}\end{bmatrix}$$
> calculate $L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}S_k,$ where $S_k$ is the sum of elements of $A^{2k+1}+B^{2k+1}$

Naturally, what I tried first is to handcheck if there is a pattern for raising $A$ and $B$ to a power. What I got is:
$$A^{2k} = \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^kI_2$$
and
$$B^k=\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{k-1}B$$

Then:

$$S_k= \text{Sum-of-elemets}(A^{2k}\cdot A + B^{2k+1}) = \text{Sum-of-elemets}(\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^k \cdot I_2 \cdot A + \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{2k} \cdot B)$$

The sum of $A$'s elements is $0$, thus the left term is $0$. The sum of $B$'s elements is $\frac{32}{9}$, so:

$$S_k = \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^k \cdot \frac{32}{9}$$

Finally:
$$L = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n S_k = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^k \cdot \frac{32}{9} = \frac{32}{9} \cdot \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1-\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n+1}}{1-\frac{2}{3}} = \frac{32}{9} \cdot 3 $$

However, I don't think this is correct. My workbook says the answer is $\frac{32}{5}$, so it seems I'm close but not quite there. I am also not sure at all how there's a $5$ in this whole deal. That being said, any ideas where I am wrong? I wasn't not able to find that out.

Comment: In your expression for $S_k$ it should be $\left( \frac 2 3 \right)^{2k}B$.

Comment: Indeed, you are right, but that, unfortunately, does not change the final result of the limit.

Comment: Are you sure that nothing changes? Now $S_k = \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{2k} \cdot \frac{32}{9} = \left(\frac{4}{9}\right)^{k} \cdot \frac{32}{9}$.

Comment: Oh, you're so right! So dumb of me, I completely forgot about the denominator changing as well. Thank you so much for helping me with such a dumb mistake!